# Build a function savings_calculator(PMT, n, i)` that calculates your customer's savings at retirement

Tags: python, python-3.x

i was working on a project were i had to write a code that calculates a customers savings when they retire:

```
def savings_calculator(PMT, n, i):
    FV = 0
    for j in range(n):
        interest = FV * i
        FV = FV + interest
        FV = FV + PMT
        FV = round(FV,2)
    return FV
```

Problem is once i round off  FV i sometimes get a wrong value

Test cases below are supposed to return true:

savings_calculator(20000, 15, 0.1) == 635449.63  True

savings_calculator(10000, 20, 0.1) == 572749.99  this returns false because rounding off return the wrong value

Comment: Please post your code with the proper indentation! It will make it a lot easier to help

Comment: As JackT's answer notes, you shouldn't round at intermediate steps. As a general scientific rule of thumb, never round at intermediate steps because you will compound error over time.

Comment: If the project has specified additional requirements please share these to give us a better understanding of your problem

Answer (score 1):

If you don't round at each iteration and only do it at the end you should get the correct answer:

```
def savings_calculator(PMT, n, i):
    FV = 0 
    for j in range(n):
        interest = FV * i 
        FV = FV + interest 
        FV = FV + PMT

    FV = round(FV,2)

    return FV
```

Rounding essentially introduces a small error by reducing precision. Over many iterations this error adds up so rounding should only be done at the end.